# How to put files with SftpOutboundGateway MPUT command properly?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I want to upload all files from the local folder `~/sftp-outbound/Export`
to a SFTP server. The folder contains two files:

- foo1.TEST.txt
- foo2.TEST.txt

I am doing it with the `MPUT` command of a `SftpOutboundGateway` within a Flow/Subflow DSL style (actually there are more gateway methods which I have removed for better focus and readability).

My configuration is this:

```
@Bean
public TransferChannel myChannel() {
    LOG.debug("myChannel");
    TransferChannel channel = new TransferChannel();
    channel.setHost(myEnv.getSftpHost());
    channel.setPort(myEnv.getSftpPort());
    channel.setUser(myEnv.getSftpUser());
    channel.setPrivateKey(myEnv.getSftpPrivateKey());
    channel.setPassword(myEnv.getSftpPassword());
    return channel;
}

@Bean
public TransferContext myContext(TransferChannel myChannel) {
    LOG.debug("myContext");
    TransferContext context = new TransferContext();
    context.setEnabled(env.isEnabled());
    context.setChannel(myChannel);
    context.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    context.setLocalDir(env.getLocalDir());
    context.setLocalFilename(env.getLocalFilename());
    context.setRemoteDir(env.getRemoteDir());
    return context;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> myFactory(TransferChannel myChannel) {
    LOG.debug("myFactory");
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost(myChannel.getHost());
    sf.setPort(myChannel.getPort());
    sf.setUser(myChannel.getUser());
    if (myChannel.getPrivateKey() != null) {
        sf.setPrivateKey(myChannel.getPrivateKey());
    } else {
        sf.setPassword(myChannel.getPassword());
    }
    sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(sf);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow(SessionFactory<LsEntry> myFactory, TransferContext myContext) {
    LOG.debug("myFlow");
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myGateway.class, g -> g    
                .header("method", args -> args.getMethod().getName()))
        .log()
        .route(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get("method", String.class),
                r -> r
                        .subFlowMapping("mput", f2 -> f2
                                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(
                                        remoteFileTemplate(myFactory,
                                                new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(
                                                        "headers['" + FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY + "']")),
                                        Command.MPUT, "payload"))
                        ))
        .get();
}

@Bean
public RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry> remoteFileTemplate(SessionFactory<LsEntry> sessionFactory,
        Expression directory) {
    RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry> template = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sessionFactory);
    template.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(directory);
    template.setAutoCreateDirectory(false);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}

public interface MyGateway {
    List<String> mput(String localDir,
            @Header(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY) String remoteDirectory);
}
```

The call of the `MyGateway` method is:

```
@Autowired
private MyGateway gate;

...
String localFilename = "~/sftp-outbound/Export";
LOG.debug("runAsTask mput={}", localFilename);
jobLOG.info("put files to SFTP: {}", localFilename);
List<String> result = gate.mput(localFilename, env.getRemoteDir());
LOG.debug("runAsTask, files transferred, result={}", result);
```

It comes with the following LOG output:

```
2022-10-21 00:02:00.000  INFO [] --- [pool-125-thread-1]  job-ExportData                           : put files to SFTP: ~/sftp-outbound/Export
2022-10-21 00:02:00.001  INFO [] --- [pool-125-thread-1]  o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=~/cdb/sftp-outbound/Export, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@ce6c62d4, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@ce6c62d4, id=02f7972e-ef06-2297-b1dd-fed5cd75a2d2, method=mput, file_remoteDirectory=data/export, timestamp=1666303320001}]
2022-10-21 00:02:00.008 DEBUG [] --- [pool-125-thread-1]  .l.c.c.j.ExportDataTask                  : runAsTask, files transferred, result=[data/export/02f7972e-ef06-2297-b1dd-fed5cd75a2d2.msg]
```

One sees two things:

1. there is only one file transferred instead of two
2. the remote filename is
   `02f7972e-ef06-2297-b1dd-fed5cd75a2d2.msg` instead of
   `foo1.TEST.txt` or `foo2.TEST.txt`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

Trying to find the problem I slightly changed the Integration Flow configuration, setting the remote directory inline to make the RemoteFileTemplate bean obsolete:

```
.subFlowMapping("mput", f2 -> f2
        .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(myFactory, Command.MPUT, "payload")
                .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectoryExpression(myContext.getRemoteDir()))
```

Following your answer, Artem, I changed the SftpOutboundGateway method's parameter to type `java.io.File` as follows:

```
public interface MyGateway {
    List<String> mput(File localDir);
}
```

The `mput` gateway method call is now:

```
List<String> result = gate.mput(new File(localFilename));
```

But this did not resolve my problem. Now I get the following error:

```
.subFlowMapping("mput", f2 -> f2
    .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(myFactory, Command.MPUT, "payload")
            .autoCreateDirectory(false)
            .remoteDirectoryExpression(myContext.getRemoteDir()))


2022-10-22 00:11:30.321 ERROR [] --- [pool-18-thread-1]  .l.c.c.j.MyExportTask : MyExports failed! Exception: {}

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'data' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessage' - maybe not public or not valid?
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpDivide.getValueInternal(OpDivide.java:49)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpMinus.getValueInternal(OpMinus.java:98)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:375)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:171)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:129)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.java:107)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:325)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.lambda$send$0(RemoteFileTemplate.java:301)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:439)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:301)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:289)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.put(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:807)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.lambda$doPut$11(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:793)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.invoke(RemoteFileTemplate.java:471)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doPut(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:792)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:301)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:289)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.put(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:807)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.lambda$doPut$11(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:793)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.invoke(RemoteFileTemplate.java:471)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doMput(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:854)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:594)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:213)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:195)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46)
        at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:96)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:86)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:514)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:488)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:648)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:573)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:540)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:540)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:529)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1232.mput(Unknown Source)
        at com.lhsystems.cdb.cdbjob.job.MyExportTask.runAsTask(MyExportTask.java:73)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

I have no clue what causes that exception. The changed `SubflowMapping` even does not use a SPEL expression anymore. Any help is highly welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you send a `String localFilename` to that gateway.

The logic there fails to this then:

```
else if (payload instanceof String) {
    file = new File((String) payload);
}
```

And according to your observation and execution result we end up here:

```
    else if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        return doPut(requestMessage);
    }
```

Some way it does not recognize the file against your `~/sftp-outbound/Export` as a dir and just performs a plain `PUT` with a single file.

Try to resolve your `~/sftp-outbound/Export` as a `File` object and send already that one to this gateway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Artem! I changed my source but got an SPEL exception. I edited my question with the new problem. Please, have another look!

Comment: Sorry, but your new exception is not relevant to the config you show. It does mention a `PUT` operation, but I think this is something else in other config place. It fails in some expression with `data` property access attempt, some minus and `/` operator. I guess it is some path resolution like `/data-` or though . These kind of literals have to be wrapped to single quotes.

Comment: Artem, I put in the entire exception stack: it is saying it was my mput command. I tried `'data/my-export'` as remote directory, `'data/my\-export'`, `"data/my-export"`, `"data/my\-export"`, even `"data"`. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: We have to see what is exactly that your property value for remote dir, but as far as you do only static value but still as an expression then it has to be like this: `”‘data/my-export’”` - the literal in the expression has to be wrapped with a single quote.

Comment: You're so right. This version I didn't try. With the value `"'data/my-export'"` in my YAML file it worked. I am not fully aware of for what it has to be exactly this way, but the `SpelEvaluationException` is gone and the `mput` works as expected. Thanks a lot, Artem!